# Binding a local var in deftemplate for enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm brand new to clojure and the web development stack. I'm trying to use enlive to set values in an HTML template:

```
(en/deftemplate project-main-page
  (en/xml-resource "project-main.html")
  [id]
  [:#project-name] (en/content (str "Name: " ((get-project id) :name)))
  [:#project-desc] (en/content (str "Desc: " ((get-project id) :desc))))
```

This works fine to set my two HTML elements, but it involves a repeated call to my function `get-project`. At the moment this just reads from a local map, but eventually it will involve some external storage access, so I'd prefer to just perform it once in this function.

I was thinking of using `let`:

```
(en/deftemplate project-main-page
  (en/xml-resource "project-main.html")
  [id]
  (let [project (get-project id)]
    [:#project-name] (en/content (str "Name: " (project :name)))
    [:#project-desc] (en/content (str "Desc: " (project :desc)))))
```

But this only affects the description element and ignores the name forms.

What is the best way to bind a local var within `deftemplate`?

Comment: Try running `macroexpand` on your deftemplate, it could be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enlive's `deftemplate` macro expects a series of tag/content pairs after the args vector (the args vector is `[id]` in your example). You can't just stick a `let` in there because the macro isn't expecting a `let` form, so when it does its splicing everything gets messed up and results in the behavior you described above.

One way you could fix this would be to write your own `deftemplate` macro that allows binding definitions using the identifiers in the args vector. Example:

```
(alt/deftemplate project-main-page
  (en/xml-resource "project-main.html")
  [id]
  [project (get-project id)]
  [:#project-name] (en/content (str "Name: " (project :name)))
  [:#project-desc] (en/content (str "Desc: " (project :desc))))
```

The `deftemplate` macro is a simple wrapper around `template`, which uses `snippet*` and this is probably where you'd need to insert your changes:

```
(defmacro snippet* [nodes args & forms]
  `(let [nodes# (map annotate ~nodes)]
     (fn ~args
       ; You could add let bindings here since args are in scope
       (doall (flatmap (transformation ~@forms) nodes#)))))
```

The other option—which might be simpler since you don't have to muck around in the library code—would be to add a level of indirection to your `get-project` function to cache results. You might try the [core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/) library.

Comment: I have updated (albeit untested) versions of the `deftemplate` and `snippet*` macros if you need them, but I wouldn't want to rob you of the chance to make the changes yourself and learn a bit more about macros!

Comment: Thanks. I'm still really just starting to learn and haven't got my head around macro syntax yet. I'll have a go and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Macros are kind of crazy at first, but once you get your head around the syntax-quote they're not so bad. Just don't forget to come back and share what you come up with! :D

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood  what you are trying to achieve; you could also try using the transformation macro provided by enlive.

```
(defn main-page [{:keys [name desc] :as project}]
 (en/transformation
   [:#project-name] (en/content (str "Name: " name)
   [:#project-desc] (en/content (str "Desc: " desc))))


(en/deftemplate project-main-page
  (en/xml-resource "project-main.html")
  [id]
   (main-page (get-project id)))
```

The code is untested, but I hope it conveys a different way to do what you need